# Как правильно вытянуть данные с созданного gameObject-а?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Опять же не могу правильно назвать тему, но сейчас всё поясню.

В главном меню(сцене main) я нажимаю кнопку новая игра и запускается скрипт по создании карты с ресурсами и самое главное заполняются данные о игроке(health, shield, fuel и другие характеристики для его дефолтных настроек). Все эти созданные данные сохраняются в файл. Сохранение произошло успешно, тогда загружается сцена map. В которой в первую очередь срабатывает скрипт WorldBuilder, который строит карту ресурсов, создаёт игрока(со всеми нужными характеристиками) во общем строит мир по этому save-file. Он всё делает норм, к нему претензий нету.

Суть в том, что созданный игрок имеет скрипты Player, Health, Shield, Fuel которые наследуются от MonoBehaviour. В них есть поля(переменные) с которыми работают другие скрипты на сцене. Эти другие скрипты доступаются к значениям через static Instance. Например с Player.Instance.Depth работает скрипт HandlerTemperature, который исходя глубины нахождения игрока(Depth) высчитывает урон(чем глубже тем больше урона). Но после того как я убрал игрока в префаб и начал его создавать начали выскакивать NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HandlerTemperature.FixedUpdate (). И это не единственный скрипт, по сути скрипты которые доступаются статически к поля игрока(к значениям скриптов которые 'висят' на игроке) начинают выдавать такие ошибки. Когда игрок был уже дефолтно при загрузке сцены а не создавался в WorldBuilder такого не было. Как по мне, я может быть неправильно доступаюсь до полей(именно статически).

Может мой принцип роботы вообще не правильный. И подход статического доступа до данных также. Я не знаю. Подскажите кто хоть немного понял с того что я написал.

Answer (score 1):

Он не правильный потому, что ты используешь статику, нужно нормально пробрасывать зависимости. Должен же быть какой-нибудь класс отвечающий за течение сессии и знающий и о персонаже и о врагах и может передать ссылку на игрока им.

А ошибка потому, что ты обращаешься к игроку раньше, чем он создан, то есть ни к чему, NullReference

Comment: по поводу NullReference то я понимаю. А от 'Должен же быть какой-нибудь класс отвечающий за течение сессии и знающий и о персонаже и о врагах и может передать ссылку на игрока им'  такого нету. Можешь вкратце накидать код чтобы я более менее понял. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

То что ты используешь `static Instance` это как я понимаю паттерн одиночка?

Если это так и возможно ты не совсем понял как работает данный `static`, и ты создаешь персонажа через префаб в определенный момент то `FixedUpdate()` ищет
данного персонажа и срабатывает в моменты когда он ещё не создался, и выдает ошибку `NullReference` и ломает тебе всё, первое решение которое могу применить это установить проверку в `FixedUpdate()` на наличие данного обьекта

```
    if (Player.Instance != null)
    {
        // code
    }
```

То что писал @Yaroslav, ранее говорит о каком нибудь обьекте который хранит в себе данные ссылки по типу персонажа (`Player.Instance`) и других полей необходимых игре в процессе

Немного информации про `static` в случае если нужно разьяснение по нему, если ты хочешь использовать `static` метод или поля не создавая обьект на сцене, они не должны иметь зависимости то есть никак не должны обращаться к не статическим полям и методам, буквально иметь весь функционал внутри тела и не выходить за него